# Bar plot with Y-axis break and error bar

Tags: r

I am trying to make a barplot with error bar y-axis break. I know the gap.plot of plotrix package can do this but I don't like the appearance of pot. I followed the code given **[HERE](http://sickel.net/blogg/?p=688)** and it is working for me except I don't know how to put the error bar. My code is like this

```
# dataset:
data=data.frame(CAx=c(120),CAp=c(32),CTAx=c(12),CTAp=c(4),MTAX=c(6),MTSAx=c(3))

lower=c(0,55)
upper=c(95,140)
y_outer=21

lowspan=c(0,11)
topspan=c(lowspan[2]+1,21)

ylabel="y-axis value"
xlabel="x-axis value"
legendtext=c('C-Ax','C-Ap','CT-Ax','CT-Ap','MT-AX','MTS-Ax')

cnvrt.coords <-function(x,y=NULL){
  xy <- xy.coords(x,y, recycle=TRUE)
  cusr <- par('usr')
  cplt <- par('plt')  
  plt <- list()
  plt$x <- (xy$x-cusr[1])/(cusr[2]-cusr[1])
  plt$y <- (xy$y-cusr[3])/(cusr[4]-cusr[3])
  fig <- list()
  fig$x <- plt$x*(cplt[2]-cplt[1])+cplt[1]
  fig$y <- plt$y*(cplt[4]-cplt[3])+cplt[3]
  return( list(fig=fig) )
}

subplot <- function(fun, x, y=NULL){
  old.par <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
  on.exit(par(old.par))
  xy <- xy.coords(x,y)
  xy <- cnvrt.coords(xy)$fig
  par(plt=c(xy$x,xy$y), new=TRUE)
  fun
  tmp.par <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
  return(invisible(tmp.par))
}

plot(c(0,1),c(0,y_outer),type='n',axes=FALSE,ylab=ylabel,xlab='',lwd=7)
subplot(barplot(as.matrix(data),col=heat.colors(2),ylim=lower,xpd=FALSE,las=3),x=c(0,1),y=lowspan)

subplot(barplot(
as.matrix(data),
col=heat.colors(2),
ylim=upper,
xpd=FALSE,
names.arg=vector(mode="character",length=length(data))), 
x=c(0,1),
y=topspan)

lowertop=lowspan[2]+0.1     # Where to end the lower axis
breakheight=0.5   # Height of the break
upperbot=lowertop+breakheight # Where to start the upper axes
markerheight=0.4 # Heightdifference for the break markers
markerwidth=.04  # With of the break markers
abline(h = 0, col = "black")
lines(c(0,0),c(1,lowertop))
lines(c(markerwidth/-2,markerwidth/2),c(lowertop-        
markerheight/2,lowertop+markerheight/2))
lines(c(0,0),c(upperbot,14))
lines(c(markerwidth/-2,markerwidth/2),c(upperbot-    
markerheight/2,upperbot+markerheight/2))
```

and plot look like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `subplot` to your advantage, namely that it uses `cnvrt.coords` to calculate the correct coordinates and that `fun` can be any expression evaluated with these new coordinates

So if we create the desired figure *within* the subplot function, the new coordinates should be used.

```
data=data.frame(CAx=120,CAp=32,CTAx=12,CTAp=4,MTAX=6,MTSAx=3)

lower=c(0,55)
upper=c(95,140)
y_outer=21

lowspan=c(0,11)
topspan=c(lowspan[2]+1,21)

ylabel="y-axis value"
xlabel="x-axis value"
legendtext=c('C-Ax','C-Ap','CT-Ax','CT-Ap','MT-AX','MTS-Ax')

plot(c(0,1),c(0,y_outer),type='n',axes=FALSE,ylab=ylabel,xlab='',lwd=7)
subplot({
  y <- as.matrix(data)
  bp <- barplot(y,col=heat.colors(2),ylim=lower,xpd=FALSE,las=3)
  arrows(bp, y * .95, bp, y * 1.05, xpd = NA, angle = 90, code = 3,
         length = .1, col = ifelse(y > max(lower), 0, 1))
},x=c(0,1),y=lowspan)

subplot({
  bp <- barplot(y, col=heat.colors(2), ylim=upper, xpd=FALSE,
          names.arg=vector(mode="character",length=length(data)))
  arrows(bp, y * .95, bp, y * 1.05, xpd = NA, angle = 90, code = 3,
         length = .1, col = ifelse(y > max(lower), 1, 0))
}, x=c(0,1), y=topspan)
```

[image]